# I can't build and install a project with Cmake on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cmake

I really need some help to build a simple project with Cmake with Jenkins.

I downloaded the Cmake plugin on Jenkins.

I configured it in the job :

[image]

and in Global Tool Configuration :

[image]

But then it doesn't work. Here are the end of the logs before the Jenkins build fails :

```bash
+ ls
CMakeLists.txt
MathFunctions
TutorialConfig.h.in
build
tutorial.cxx
[build] $ cmake /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project
ERROR: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Project/build"): error=2, No such file or directory
Build step 'CMake Build' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't understand why there is no proper step-by-step tutorial to create something that common as a Cmake build with Jenkins.

Comment: The error message `Cannot run program "cmake"` means that it cannot find `cmake` executable. Have you installed CMake?

Comment: The [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cmakebuilder/#plugin-content-screenshots-for-the-impatient) has screenshots for the impatient. Did you [configure properly](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Configuration) ?

Comment: I hadn't done the Global Tool Configuration because I thought cmake would be automatically on my Jenkins node as soon as I get the plugin. My bad. But I still get the same error. (I updated my post with the new configuration). btw, I still don't manage to find the "Tool Configuration" https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tool+Configuration I've searched in all Jenkins tho... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I managed to pull it off.

I uninstalled the Cmake plugin which seems to be useless apparently...

And I simply installed Cmake manually on the Jenkins container.